# Android convert byte array back to NdefMessage

Tags: android, ndef, hce

I am on a project which use the nfc to transfer data. Device A as HCE and device B as reader. In device A, I convert NdefMessage into byte array then send to device B. So my problem now is in device B, how I convert the received byte array data back to NdefMessage?

Comment: Show the code you are reading the card with on Device B, sounds like you are reading it at a low level when you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well. Normally we just need to fetch the tag and ndefMessage from the intent received. But due to condition of the project, isodep is needed in order to retrieve the data. In the end of the process, an array byte(NdefMessage byte) is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html

You can

> Use NdefMessage(byte[]) to construct an NDEF Message from binary data,

This converts a byte array to NdefMessage

Or

https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/nfc-data-exchange-format-ndef/

Details the Ndef message and record format, so you could convert it yourself

Comment: Yes. Its correct. It cause the error last time due to some mistake I done when create Ndef record, hence cause the byte array back to NdefMessage failed. Stupid me. Thanks a lot.